# C sleep variance when ran by cron

Tags: c, cron, raspberry-pi, usleep

I wrote some C code to switch on and off some LEDs.
Actually, I want to trigger them accurate to music but haven't found a better way than using `usleep()` in between yet.

Anyway, turning on the LEDs, waiting at `usleep()` and turning off the LEDs again works pretty accurate when I call the program on the command line.

Now I'd like cron to execute the program let's say every five minutes. Therefore I added following cronjob with `crontab -e`:

```
*/5 * * * * bash ~/startShow.sh >~/log 2>&1
```

Same problem without the shell script.

```
*/5 * * * * ~/projects/startLEDShow >~/log 2>&1
```

startShow.sh

```
date
/usr/sbin/i2cset -y 1 0x40 0x00 0x21 # Preparation for communication via I2C
cd projects
./startLEDShow
```

The program is triggered every five minutes, but at some point (not always the same point) the execution seems to stop for a moment and resumes about a second later. That is only when the program is ran by cron, not when I call it from the commandLine.

Why is that so, is this perhaps due to the `usleep()` used in the program, and how can I make sure that the program execution isn't suspended for some time?

**Update 1**: Here is an extract with the usleep-section from the program

```
// Start reading
while(NULL != (word = readToChar(fp, wordBuffer))) {
    // Values for the LEDs are stored in a struct
    updateValuesForLEDs(next, word); // Update struct "next"

    usleep(((next->time/timeFactor - lastTime)*1000000)); // Wait
    lastTime = next->time / timeFactor; // Set lastTime for next iteration

    setLEDs(i2cConnection, next, buffer); // Set the LEDs to the brightness values stored in struct "next" via I2C
}
```

**Update 2:**
After ensc's comment I found way to solve my issue.

The cronjob was started with a nice value of 10 whereas most other processes' values circled around 0. Setting my job to a lower nice value (which requires root privileges) gives it a higher priority and prevents it from being paused.

```
00 20 * * * sudo nice -n -20 ~/projects/startLEDShow >~/log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here - the one containing `usleep()`?

Comment: Why do this looping with cron at all? Whats the runtime of the program? why not `while(1)` and sleep (5 minutes - current runtime)?

Comment: @Macattack: That five minute loop was just an example for a cronjob and for testing purposes. The aim is to run the program at a certain time every day.

Comment: @Christian Ternus Added an extract from the code to the description.

Comment: I recommend using a print statement to print the value of `((next->time/timeFactor - lastTime)*1000000)` to ensure it's what you think it is.

Comment: @Christian Ternus. It is, I checked that already. And the program is doing exactly as expected when I run it from the command line. Just not when cron does.

Comment: Can you try once again with a `cd ~/projects` instead of `cd projects` in your script?

Comment: @ansh0l tried, but unfortunately no improvement. Even when I create a crontab that runs the program directly, I get this issue.

Comment: cronjobs are usually running less priorized (higher nice level); parallel io (e.g. due to logging that a cronjob was executed, draining io buffers) might delay the internal delay.

Comment: @ensc Is there a way of running a crobjob higher priorized? I tried to prepend nice -n 19 ... no success.

Comment: @ensc Setting the cronjob to a lower priority helped me out finally! (See the updated description.) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you're running a real-time operating system, so `usleep` is not guaranteed to wake up your process with any guarantee of performance.  For that matter, even if your process is woken up at the right time, it's always possible for the kernel to interrupt it and do somehing else for an arbitrary amount of time.